# How invoke PL/pgSQL from command line instead of SQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I write PL/SQL scripts using Oracle and I'm trying my first PL/pgSQL script with PostgreSQL. For example, I created this test.sql file.

```
DECLARE
    v_loc_nbr         INTEGER;
BEGIN
    v_loc_nbr := 0;
END;
```

Which I try to execute using the command line:

```
\postgresql\9.3\bin\psql.exe -d postgres -f test.sql
```

but I get syntax errors like:

> psql:test.sql:4: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "v_loc_nbr"

I think the problem is it trying to execute SQL when I want it to run PL/pgSQL. What should the command be?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to explain more about this because [Erwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27326265/3682599) explained well.You need to wrap your sql inside a [**DO**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html), so your `test.sql` should write like this

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    v_loc_nbr INTEGER;
BEGIN
    v_loc_nbr := 0;
END;
$$
```

and try to execute it `\postgresql\9.3\bin\psql.exe -d postgres -f test.sql`

Answer (score 2):

Like with other [procedural languages](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xplang.html), you cannot run [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) directly.
You can only run SQL. Use plpgsql inside a [**function**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) body or wrapped in a [**`DO`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) command, where the range of `DO` commands is limited since they cannot return data.

Check out the  [plpgsql](/questions/tagged/plpgsql) tag for examples.